# How to use the Unsplash API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, rest

I'm currently working on a new personal project and it seems that I can't retrieve the images that I want from my profile since I can't authenticate properly.

My code to authenticate is the following:

```
var dotenv = require('dotenv');
var unsplash = require('unsplash-api');

dotenv.config()

var clientId = new unsplash({ clientId: process.env.myAccessKey }); //this is required to verify your application's requests
unsplash.init(clientId);
```

The issue that I'm getting is the following:

```
var clientId = new unsplash({ clientId: process.env.myAccessKey }); //this is required to verify your application's requests
               ^
TypeError: unsplash is not a constructor
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/aharo5/Desktop/javascript/unsplash_portfolio/main.js:6:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1081:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:82:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47
```

Could some one help me out with this request?

Comment: Use install wrong package. try this `npm i unsplash-js`

Comment: It is giving me the same issue, I tried the unsplash-js

Comment: correct syntax as mention on docs:  `const unsplash = createApi({accessKey: 'MY_ACCESS_KEY',});`

Comment: Yes, the 'My_Access_Key' you should replace it with the key that you have. However, you should never pass the tokens or keys at front, and that's why I'm using a .env file, and my key is called myAccesskey.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/unsplash-js#user-content-usage